# Not showing notification when new question arrives

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, web-sockets

I visit Stack Overflow daily using Chrome on Windows 7.

When I click on PHP tag and then newest tab so it doesn't give a notification as daily gives when new question arrives.

I have pinned Stack Overflow as below:

[image]

And Link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pageSize=15

Today it's not showing a notification. For that I logout and login again and also try by clearing cookies still it wont work.

Comment: Maybe all PHP questions have been answered by now?

Comment: No i am been trying from last 2 hour and i am using chrome. it works daily but today it wont work. and strange thing is when i refreshed page new questions will shows .

Comment: Why this was downvoted even without answring or suggesting any answer ?

Comment: This seems [indeed a bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezgSi.png), websocket messages are coming in but they are not pushed into the DOM. No console errors either.

Comment: @rene So why this is downvoted. And What is the sollution ?

Comment: It is downvoted because someone  [lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/158100) (or because it is lacking info on which browser (version) you use, which OS, if you are on a specific network, if the console show any errors, if other parts of the site work fine, if you still have a facebook account and if yes, why) and the solution is to wait for an SE dev.

Comment: strangely enough [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) does work.

Comment: It's expected that it doesn't work for you (realtime updates are enabled at 30 rep, and you have 14 at the time of writing). It's weird that @rene sees it as well though. It works fine here, in both Chrome and Firefox, both with a user that has access to Teams and as one that doesn't.

Comment: Turns out it looks like I can repro because PHP is in my ignored tag list. With that setting the websocket messages are still arriving but the div to show that new messages have arrived is not added to the DOM. For tag question lists that are not in my ignore list the new questions div does get added. So this is status-bydesign.

Comment: @balpha we need to update the reputation privileges thingy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the comments, this is by design.

I don't know what "as daily gives" means, but the simple fact is that you do not have enough reputation yet for getting live question list updates (the threshold is 30).

Comment: `I don't know what "as daily gives` Because i first i have reputation 100+ And It became 0 And i started again